# Exception handling in Python between backend and front end

Tags: python, validation, exception

As part of some study I am doing I am building a program with a frontend and backend module that is used to collect inputs from users. The program is functional but I now want to validate user entered data and gracefully handle exceptions without the program crashing. I've read a bit about different ways of doing this (i.e. try, except, finally) but would appreciate some guidance on the sample scenarios below which represent problems i'm trying to solve.

I need to handle this in a way where the frontend is the only module interacting with the user (i.e. no sys.stdout/sys.stdin to be in the backend). The backend should abstract as much of the processing of data and validation as possible before returning values/exceptions to the front end. Limitations are that I cannot use the print or input functions hence the use of sys, no for loops, need to handle this in as manual way as possible so I am learning the long way to help me transfer knowledge to other languages in future.

**frontend module** prompts the user down a list of questions

```
import sys
import backend

#must validate entry is string and equal to "Y" or "N"
sys.stdout.write("Would you like to buy a cake? Y/N")
likes_cake = backend.get_string(sys.stdin.readline())

#must validate entry is integer and greater than 1
sys.stdout.write("How many would you like to buy?")
buy_qty = backend.get_integer(sys.stdin.readline())

#must validate entry is float and great than 0
sys.stdout.write("How much are you willing to pay?")
buy_price = backend.get_float(sys.stdin.readline())
```

**backend module**

```
def get_string(entered_str):
    return entered_str.upper().strip()

def get_integer(entered_int):
    return int(entered_int)

def get_float(entered_float):
    return float(entered_float)
```

Comment: You have that backwards, right?  `likes_cake = backend.get_string( sys.stdin.readline() )`.  You have to read the raw data, then pass it to the validator.  And if those are generic validators, you wouldn't make the parameters `likes_cake` etc.  You would have something generic, like `def get_string(str):`.

Comment: Yes, i've corrected the sample code. I try not to use params that are close to inbuilt methods or types within python

Comment: OK, then what's the issue?  This is the right concept for what you're asking.

Comment: Well as it stands, if a user enteres a string where an int is required the program crashes with a TypeError right? So I want to learn the best way to handle anticipated exceptions and prevent the crashing and re-prompt for the correct input.

Comment: You can either check before (`if entered_int.isdigits():`) or use `try` and `except ValueError:`.  Put them in a `while True:` loop and return when you get good data.

Comment: that's exactly how i had pictured doing it with a while loop, do you think all of that conditional logic can be in the back end? How would the user know at the front end what the issue is unless we are passing a str?

Comment: If you relegate all the validation code to the front end, a malicious visitor can crash the back end by passing in invalid data. A secure design requires the back end to check all inputs. You can then choose to do additional validation in the client to improve the user experience.

Comment: If you want to talk more formally, you generally have very general guidelines (like "this must be an integer", "this must be a float", "this must be alphanumeric only").  That's great in a general-purpose backend.  Then you have what is sometimes called "business logic" ("the salary must be between 15000 and 200000", "no raise can be larger than 10%", "population cannot be negative", "the quantity field can never go to 0").  Those are sometimes in a middle layer.  It's hard to put them in a generic backend, because they are task specific.